# Software to check incoming VoIP connection

Tags: api, voip

I have a 3CX PBX setup with sip trunk which works, but sometimes callers state they can't get through (various errors).  When I try the line myself, it seems to be fine.  Callers are dialling the right number, because they do get through.

I'd like to try to do some automated testing - most likely dialling the number and hanging up immediately when the ring is detected, and recording the results

Is there any sort of software that can do that, or can be configured or scripted to do this?  I'm not averse to a bit of API coding or setup, or some other cost re getting another VoIP connection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. SIPp (any platform).
2. tSIP softphone (Windows), basic calling in loop is in Tools/Script window/Help/Examples but you would probably need to add call state checking and maybe writing this state to some kind of log file as it may be easier than reading application log later. On the other hand in case of any problems log with received/transmitted SIP messages would be useful.

Comment: Thanks, this sounds promising.  While this is most likely the answer, I'll hold off marking it as such until either I can get round to trying it, or someone else beats me to it!